# svn: E175002 Unexpected HTTP status 405 when user name had change

Tags: eclipse, apache, svn

I'm using eclipse mars.2 and subclipse 3. The configuration from svn is ok. I was working with a false user in Windows, e.g "Fran" and now that is correct, "Frank", I'm not allowed to acces to this svn.

- I had deleted everything in the Folder AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth.
- in cmd I have: `svn list https://mysubversion`
- ask me for the certificate and than p (accept)

I have the first error "svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL"
when I try once again my list command, I get the

- "svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP Status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on"
- "svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on "" failed: 405 Method not allowed"

I had readed in the Forum but everybody had Connection to the server, I don't. I can see my repository in the browser but that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to set a new user name for your SVN repository is following:

1. Open the `SVN Repository Exploring` Perspective
2. Rightclick on the repository and choose `Location Properties..`
3. Check beneath `Authentication` the textbox `User`

If that doesn't help, you probaby saved your credentials in the `Secure Storage..`

To clear the storage:

1. Go to: `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Security` -> `Secure Storage`
2. Choose the `Contents` tab
3. Search for `SVN`
4. Press `Delete`